# linq to xml - remove elements

Tags: linq-to-xml

I'd like to remove all elements of type `Item` with an attribute `view` which has not a certain value.

So if the value is XXX. Select all elements Item which have an attribute view of value != XXX.

Some of the Item elements don't have a view attribute. This elements shouldn't be selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string selector = "XXX";

Elements.Where(x => x.Name == "Item"
                 && x.Attribute("view") != null
                 && x.Attribute("view").Value != selector).Remove();
```